# How to reduce time complexity of nested for loops when each stage produces the list that the next one works on

Tags: python-3.x, time, time-complexity

I need to reduce the time complexity of my *for loops* but the issue is I **need different ranges** and **each loop provides the material for working in the next loop**. I need to compress it in a way that it takes less than 10 secs to process.

What are the ways in which I can compress these types of loops?

```
def countWays(arr, l, r):
    total = 0
    for i in range(l,r+1):
        count=0
        for k in range(1,i+1):
            itertablecomb = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(arr, k)
            for y in itertablecomb:
                if sum(list(y)) == i:
                    count=count+1
        total=total+count
    return total
```

Comment: Can you provide more details how how this function is used, what the parameters are, test data, and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The function calculates the total ways in which you can add numbers to form the function size(upper limit r).  For ex. l = 1 and r = 6 are being sent as param. The loop i will calculate all the mini func we need to run i.e. F(1),F(2),F(3)....F(5),F(6). Loop k calculates the ways to add the numbers for each func. and total is adding the no of ways for F(1),F(2)....and F(6).